# How do I add a Global Exception handler to a Metro Style App?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime

Is there any specific way to add a global exception handler to a Metro style app, just like LittleWatson in WP7 in the App.Xaml.cs file? what is the best practice and pattern to handle this?

Comment: I need that to ensure that my app doesn't crash during development, and in the event that it does at some point in the future, I want to send a log email back to itself.

Comment: It's strange that its much less functional than SL/WP7, because that could do all this.

Comment: How about UnhandledExceptionHandler in the Application class?

Comment: Did this work with you, the "UnhandledExceptionHandler"? because the event handler is never invoked!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [UnhandledException event page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.application.unhandledexception.aspx) explains why your exception is not handled by that (emphasis mine):

> This event is **only used with exceptions encountered by the XAML
>   framework**. Exceptions encountered by other Windows Runtime components
>   or parts of the application that are not connected to the XAML
>   framework will not result in this event being raised.

It goes on explaining that you should catch exceptions at the most specific time possible. As far as I know, there's no such thing as a global event handler in Windows 8 style apps.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [UnhandledException event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.application.unhandledexception.aspx) on the [Application class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.application.aspx).

Comment: Did you try this?  The exception is never invoked, as Emad says above.